# CASE statement versus temporary table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have my choice between two different techniques in converting codes to text:

```
insert into #TMP_CONVERT(code, value)
 (1, 'Uno')
,(2, 'Dos')
,(3, 'Tres')
;

coalesce(tc.value, 'Unknown') as THE_VALUE
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN #TMP_CONVERT tc
  on tc.code = x.code
```

Or

```
case x.code
when 1 then 'Uno'
when 2 then 'Dos'
when 3 then 'Tres'
else 'Unknown'
end as THE_VALUE
```

The table has about 20 million rows.
Typical size the of the code lookup table is 10 rows.

I would rather to #1 but I don't like left outer joins.

My questions are:

1. Is one faster than the other in any really meaningful way?
2. Does any SQL engine optimize this out anyway?  That is: It just reads the table into memory essentially does the case statement logic anyway?

I happen to be using tsql, but I would like to know for any number of RDBM systems because I use several.

[Edit to clarify not liking LEFT OUTER JOIN]
I use LEFT OUTER JOINS when I need them, but whenever I use them I double check my logic and data to confirm I actually need them.  Then I add a comment to the code that indicates why I am using a LEFT OUTER JOIN.  Of course I have to do a similar exercise when I use INNER JOIN; that is: make sure I am am not dropping data.

Comment: I am curious as to a use case that would favor lookup data in code rather than a static table.  Any case I have come across I create a table that can be edited by users without code changes.

Comment: Might be worth reading Eric Lippert's excellent [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/): "... If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses. Don’t write short descriptions of the horses, post them on the Internet, and ask random strangers to guess which is faster! "

Comment: What results do you get when you run them against your 20 million rows?

Answer (score 0):

There is some overhead to using a `join`.  However, if the `code` is made a primary clustered key, then the performance for the two might be comparable -- with the `join` even winning out.  Without an index, I would expect the `case` to be slightly better than the `left join`.

These are just guesses.  As with all performance questions, though, you should check on your data on your systems.

I also want to react to your not liking `left join`s.  These provide important functionality for SQL and are the right way to address this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code executed for the join will likely be substantially more than the code executed for the hardcoded `case` options.

The execution plan will have an extra join iterator along with an extra scan or seek operator (depending on the availability of a suitable index). On the positive side likely the 10 rows will all fit on a single page in `#TMP_CONVERT` and this will be in memory anyway, also being a temp table it won't bother with taking and releasing row locks each time, but still the code to latch the page, locate the correct row, and crack the desired column value out of it over 20,000,000 iterations would likely add some amount of measurable CPU time compared with looking up in a hardcoded list of values (potentially you could try nested `CASE` statements too, to perform a binary search and avoid the need for 10 branches there).

But even if there is a measurable time difference it still may not be particularly significant as a proportion of the query time as a whole. Test it. Let us know what you find...

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid creating temporary table in this case by using `with` construction. So you query might be something like this.

```
WITH TMP_CONVERT(code,value) AS -- Semicolon can be required before WITH.
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,'UNO'), 
                          (2,'DOS'),
                          (3,'Tres')
    ) tbl(code,value)
)
coalesce(tc.value, 'Unknown') as THE_VALUE
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN TMP_CONVERT tc
  on tc.code = x.code
```

OR even sub query can be used :

```
coalesce(tc.value, 'Unknown') as THE_VALUE
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN (VALUES (1,'UNO'), 
                        (2,'DOS'),
                        (3,'Tres')
        ) tc(code,value) 
        ON tc.code = x.code
```

Hope this can be helpful.